# logical AND of images in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
 image=double(imread('ooutput.jpg'));
 [M, N]=size(image); 
  masked=zeros(M,N);
  masked(1:100,1:90)=255;
     masked(175:300,1:90)=255;
     imshow(masked);
    new=uint8( masked&image);
   imshow(new);
```

I used logical and to obtain a portion of image.Here a mask is created and logically and it with image.I am not able to get the portion.instead a get complete black pixel.Can anyone point out what is the mistake in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

'masked&image' is either 1 or 0. Using uint8, both is close to black. Besides this, your code fails for all image types except grayscale uint 8.

To fix the mask issue, use:

```
image=imread('ooutput.jpg');
masked=false(M,N);
masked(1:100,1:90)=true;
masked(175:300,1:90)=true;
image(~masked)=0
imshow(image);
```

Comment: ok.I wanna do mask operation using logical AND .First i wanna create a mask and when this mask is applied to each image i get the required result.

Comment: You can only use a logical and for binary images.